# Java ClassCastException when using ? extends

Tags: java, classcastexception

I got a method getting a paramter of this type:

`NSArray<? extends FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot>`

Now when I take an element of this array I get an **ClassCastException**. My method:

```
public static List<AbstractWrapper> getWrapperList(Class<? extends IAbstractWrapper> wrapper, NSArray<? extends FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotArray){
        List<AbstractWrapper> results = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i<documentSnapshotArray.size(); i++){
            FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot doc = documentSnapshotArray.get(i);
            results.add(getWrapper(wrapper,doc));
        }
        return results;
    }
```

**Error in line 4**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: apple.NSObject cannot be cast to
>   org.moe.binding.firebasefirestore.FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot

Comment: looks like you'll need to implement a mapper

Comment: That means that whatever code which created this NSArray and returned it as an NSArray<? extends FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot> lied: it returns an NSArray that contains something else. Look where this array is created and populated, and fix that code.

Comment: @Stultuske could you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Is NSArray your implementation of Array? Could you put this class here please?

Comment: @RafałSokalski unfortunately it is not my implementation. I am using intel multi-os-engine.

Comment: @JBNizet this is what I am afraid of, because I get this array from code which I didn't write and have no influence in.

Comment: try to add just simple if(documentSnapshotArray.get(i) instanceof FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot) then Assign it to "doc" and do what you want

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls `getWrapperList` and in particular what is the actual argument passed in as `documentSnapshotArray` and how is it defined at the call site?

Comment: You seem to be mixing parameterized types with raw types, e.g. in `List<AbstractWrapper> results = new ArrayList();`. Don't use raw types. Enable the warnings in your IDE to warn you whenever you do this. I suspect you've also used a raw type when you declared the actual parameter for `documentSnapshotArray`. If you had always used parameterized types and avoided raw types, this error would have been caught at compile time instead of run time.

Answer (score 1):

It might happen because object you are getting from `documentSnapshotArray.get(i)` cannot cast to `FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot`, Verify this by

```
System.out.println(documentSnapshotArray.get(i) instanceof FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot);  
// if true problem is something else but, 
// if false then object you are getting is not a type of FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot
```

**Fix to this problem is:-**

- if you are getting an object that is not a type of
  FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot, then you should fix code where
  documentSnapshotArray is generated and make sure each element you put
  in documentSnapshotArray should type of (IS-A)
  FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot.

Comment: yeah shure it cannot cast, that is what the error says. This is not a fix to the problem. You should post this as a comment, not as an answer. Thanks for your effort anyway :)

Comment: @progNewbie to be fair, you didn't ask any question, just presented a problem. That can very well be interpreted as you asking what the issue with this error is.